# Bug on My InstaRaider Patch

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I get InstaRaider script from https://github.com/akurtovic/InstaRaider but this version have style statement issues. And I patched this script for new style of Instagram but it crashes when I download 15th photo. If start it from 15th photo it crashes again in 29th photo. Can you help me to solve this interesting bug?

---

Crash Log:

```
$ python2 instaRaider.py -u randomuser
randomuser has 104 photos on Instagram.
Loading Selenium WebDriver...
Loading Instagram profile...
...
Raiding Instagram...
Saving photos to ./Images/randomuser/
------
Photos saved so far:
---------10--------20--------30--------40--------50
##############Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "instaRaider.py", line 234, in <module>
    raider.getPhotos(source, userName, count)
  File "instaRaider.py", line 163, in getPhotos
    rawUrl = x['style']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 905, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'style'
```

Comment: Best to ask the developer directly. They have listed their email address on the github page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram changed its website causing this BeautifulSoup error. The latest commits to InstaRaider should have fixed this issue now.